# How to set a TODO deadline at the end of the month in orgmode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I set a deadline on TODO for the last weekday of the month?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this function will do it.

```
(defun last-working-day-deadline ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((date (calendar-current-date)) 
  (day (calendar-extract-day date))
  (month (calendar-extract-month date))
  (year (calendar-extract-year date))
  (lastday (calendar-last-day-of-month month year)))
  ;; workdays have "names" of 1 2 3 4 or 5
  (while (not (memq (calendar-day-of-week (list month lastday year)) '(1 2 3 4 5)))
  (decf lastday))
 (org-deadline nil (format "%s-%s-%s" year month lastday))))
```